# Get constant value by variable value

Tags: php

I need to fetch a constant value. The constant name is stored in a variable.

```
<?php

define('SomeConstant', 12345);

$variable = 'SomeConstant';

?>
```

How would I echo "12345" using the variable?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The constants are paths. Certain files can be loaded from different directories depending on a parameter in a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [constant function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

```
echo constant($variable);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

define('SomeConstant', 12345);

$variable = SomeConstant;

echo $variable;

?>
```

Comment: Yea idk why I didn't think of that

Comment: +1 for an answer which would result in better benchmark than using constant() function.

Comment: actually I didnt use this approach because not all constants are always defined

Comment: @KarmicDice: Not really an answer to the OP's question though

Comment: @nick: Are you sure constants are the tool for the job here? Sounds like you want an array...

Comment: I just checked the comments. Perhaps you are right @Eric. nick can you re-phrase your question?

Comment: @KarmicDice: I think he wants to do what `constant` does. However, there's nothing wrong with your answer as a "you shouldn't be wanting to do that" reponse.

Comment: The path constants are defined in config files.. i use the same function to load function files for both the site and the admin panel. however, when loading from the site, the admin constant is not defined. it should never come to the point of undefined constant error, but i just want to make sure of that by securing it fully.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php):

```
<?php
define('SomeConstant', 12345);
$variable = 'SomeConstant';
assert(SomeConstant == constant($variable));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the define like its meant to be:

```
define('SomeConstant', 12345);

$variable = SomeConstant;
echo  SomeConstant;
```